# Moving a CSS Element Vertically Without JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, css-position

Is there anyway I can make an HTML div move down while scrolling instead of moving up without using javascript? I know you can use window.onscroll = function() { } and have that move the position of an object while scrolling, but is there anyway I can move an object down with just CSS and HTML?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to retain your `div` on the viewport while scrolling down.

There are 2 ways for it.

1. Make the element position `fixed` and apply positioning to that element.
2. Make parent element position relative and make your `div` position `sticky` and apply positioning.

Positioning means adding any one of the top, right, bottom, and left properties.

```css
.parent {
  height: 1200px;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.floating {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Hi this is parent</p>
  <div class="floating">
    This is floating element
  </div>
</div>
```